# Get store date and time in checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, shipping, datetime

I'm creating a shipping module, and I need to get current store time and date at the time. in my requirement, I need to check if the day is `Friday` or not. Then after that, I need to check if time is earlier than 3.30pm (15.30) or not.

I've looked into `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $datetime` but it doesn't provide what I'm looking for.

How can I get store date/time and format it for my requirement? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get store date and time:-

```
public function __construct(Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
 ...)
{
    ...
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
    ....
}
public function execute()
{
    $date = $this->timezone->date();
    $currentdate = $date->format('d/m/y');     
    $time = $date->format('H:i:s A');  

}
```